# Is ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Even A Contender?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages, razor

I'm just getting into ASP.NET web pages with Razor.  Based on what it has to offer, would you choose it for your application?  It seems to me the ASP.NET MVC framework gives Razor more of an edge because of everything MVC has to offer; it's nice that the web pages framework has some helper components from the WebMatrix DLL, but most of the examples having all the code in one file, plus the reliance on a new set of API's (via webmatrix) is a turnoff to me.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing Web Forms, you shouldn't be writing any code in your .ASPX page to begin with.

Comment: @Michael - I surely don't. Unless of course you want to contribute to the unmaintainable mess people have created with Web Forms over the past 10 years. Then blame the technology. "ohh web forms are crap, viewstate is crap, i don't understand how to use it correctly but it's all crap!".

Comment: Old post, but hopefully helpful. `WebPages` (now v3) has it's beauty in simplicity. That doesn't mean it's not ready for prime time. The ease in it's default routing scheme (without effort/touching  `routes`) is pretty cool and _easy_. And since Asp.net is Asp.net, you can have `App_Code` and maintain code there, have access to any other ASP.net feature (bundling, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor View Engine + ASP.NET MVC is a great combination. Razor definitely seems like the view engine of choice most of the time because it is syntactically much easier to read and work around than ASPX. This benefit alone is huge because you can have developers that are solely focused on HTML and UI development, and have them be able to work around the syntax.

The biggest problem with Razor so far has been it's intellisense support. But, it looks as if the latest version of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) solved that problem nicely, and I'm sure the support for Razor will continue to get better.

Comment: I agree. I've been super pleased with my Razor dabbling. Also, maybe it's just be but the generated markup is much cleaner in the cases I've used it.